# Ajax.ActionLink repeating the same exact GET request multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I'm learning MVC and am currently making a simple [SCRUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29) tracking system as I go along.

The problem I'm having is that when an Ajax.ActionLink is clicked, I run the same ajax action once for every scrum card displayed on the page.

[image]

As you can see, I have 9 cards displayed and I get 9 identical GET requests. (The action link is actually the color wheel image in the lower right hand side of the card).

SingleCard.cshtml (View) - "ColorPicker" is the name of my action.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

...

<div class="card_footer" id="card_footer_id_@(Model.ID)">
    <div class="card_tags">
        [Tag1] [Tag2] [Tag3]
    </div>
    <div class="card_colorwheel_icon">
    @Ajax.ImageActionLink("../Content/Images/color_wheel.png", "Color Wheel", "ColorPicker", new { cardid = Model.ID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ColorPickerDisplay" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The ImageActionLink is a helper I'm using, but it works exactly like the normal ActionLink

HomeController.cs (Controller)

```
    public ActionResult ColorPicker(int cardid)
    {
        var currentcard = db.Cards.Single(x => x.ID == cardid);

        var colors = new List<CardRGB>();
        var cards = db.Cards.ToList();
        foreach (var card in cards)
        {
            colors.Add(new CardRGB 
                {
                    CardId = card.ID,
                    Red = (int)card.BG_Red,
                    Blue = (int)card.BG_Blue,
                    Green = (int)card.BG_Green
                });
        }

        // disctint

        var model = new ColorPickerViewModel()
        {
            Colors = colors,
            Red = (int) currentcard.BG_Red,
            Green = (int) currentcard.BG_Green,
            Blue = (int) currentcard.BG_Blue
        };

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Does anyone know why this code is running once per card?

EDIT: As requested!

```
public static class ImageActionLinkHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ImageActionLink(
        this AjaxHelper helper,
        string imageUrl,
        string altText,
        string actionName,
        object routeValues,
        AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
        {
            var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
            builder.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
            builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
            builder.MergeAttribute("title", altText);
            var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName, routeValues, ajaxOptions);
            var html = link.ToHtmlString().Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
            return new MvcHtmlString(html);
        }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown this `ImageActionLink` custom helper. You say that it works as a normal `ActionLink` but we can't know this until we see its code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the HTML of your page. In your singlecard.cshtml there is the line:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For every card again you include the javascript, so it is included 9 times. Therefore 9 requests will be sent to the server.

Solution: put the script-include on page level, not on card level.

Comment: Thanks :) I was told I needed to include that file for it to work, but it wasn't clear at which level. This makes a lot of sense. Although I ended up getting rid of the action link all together and instead am using $.ajax to take care of business

Comment: Thanks, the HTM investigation has solved my problem too :)